# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: website.User.purchasedProducts, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to setup a tag lib to check if a user purchased a product. However, when my taglib is run, I get this error:

```
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/derbypro/index.gsp:124] Error executing tag <g:ifPurchased>: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: website.User.purchasedProducts, could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: website.User.purchasedProducts, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Here is my tag lib:

```
package website

class PurchasedProductTagLib {
    def ifPurchased = { attrs, body ->
        if (!session.user) return

        if (Product.findById(attrs.product) in session.user.purchasedProducts) { // <-- error here
            out << body()
        }
    }

    def ifNotPurchased = { attrs, body ->
        if (!(Product.findById(attrs.product) in session.user?.purchasedProducts)) {
            out << body()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my User domain class:

```
package website

import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt

class User {
    String username
    String passwordHash
    String email

    static hasMany = [purchasedProducts: Product]

    User(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt())
        this.email = email
    }
}
```

This only seems to be happening after logging in, if the user registers instead (and is redirected back to this page), this error does not happen.

I have my tag libs nested inside one-another, if that does anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well! As logs say that `No session`. You are using an object which is in detached state. Hence, either attach the object back or just fetch the object by id.

```
if(!session.user.isAttached()){
     session.user.attach();
}
```

Or

```
Long id = session.user.id.toLong();
User user = User.get(id);
```

Both the way you will attach the object to a session.

**Edit**

Another solution could be to eager load the hasMany part. But I would not prefer this solution as it will slow down my domain fetch. Also, it would fetch hasMany data that might not be required in all places.

Comment: Why would it enter this detached state?

Comment: Well there could be several reason. As per my knowledge when we try to do any operation related to DB we open a session and close it. Here the object you fetched is from HttpSession which is having a Lazy fetch type associated. Which means the hasMany part would be loaded from databse  when it is needed. Now because  there is no session, it's unable to lazy fetch from database.